# How do count the number of popup windows?

Tags: javascript

How do i count the number of popup windows in script. I mean in `document.forms.length`that return the number of elements in a form, I'm trying also to check for popup window if it found and return the number of popup windows.

 In this example of page script on web:

```
<script>
window.open("www.stackoverflow.com");
window.open("www.example.com");
window.open("www.google.com");
</script>
```

It should be return number 3 as there are three `window.open()`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no connection from a document to popups it spawned unless you explicitly keep track of them yourself.

```
var popups = [
    window.open("www.stackoverflow.com"),
    window.open("www.example.com"),
    window.open("www.google.com")
];
popups = popups.filter(defined => defined); // Remove any falsy values which represent closed or failed popups
console.log(popups.length);
```

Also note, that the popup blocking algorithm browsers implement will block all three of the windows in your code (because (a) not in response to a user action and (b) multiple popups in the same action).

Comment: I use the content page ( ex. www.exampleWeb.com) to search for these popups window, which I don't know how many popups window exist there.